# Creating a Banner For Website [Web Design / CSS]

Tags: html, css, web, photoshop

I've been trying to figure out what the standard approach for this is or what might be considered "good web development standards", but how do websites generally implement their banners?

For instance, I know that you can create the background for it using CSS and position an image  and text on top of the CSS background to create the banner but lets say that you want to position a logo with white space surrounding it. How would you get rid of the white space to match the background CSS? Does this require additionally software or is there a CSS hack that people generally use to fix this issue?

Or for another approach you could just design the entire banner with Photoshop and resize the image so that it matches the header of the website.

By banner, I mean something like the navigation bar on the top of the website like
http://www.springsource.org/

What approach do web developers use and why?

Comment: I personally prefer making it the background of my header element, makes most sense to me semantically. Not sure I understand your white space concerns, making the logo with a transparent background leaves no problems as I see it

Comment: Thank you for your response :) Umm...I guess a question I might add is how would I make the logo background transparent? is there a specific CSS property? or should I be using Photoshop to match the logo background with that of the CSS background?

Comment: Simply pop up photoshop, and upon creating a new image, you can select the color of the background - where you should choose transparent - old image: http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/5607/seriouslyx.jpg

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thanks for explaining it. I'm not too sure why I didn't think of this >.<

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere, good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is way too general a question to receive a good, comprehensive answer, but what I would do is first think about the markup, rather than focus on what the site will look like. (note that the site you linked to doesn't follow this approach at all).

#### HTML

```
<h1 class="title">Spring Source Community</h1>
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="/features">Features</a></li>
  <li><a href="/get_started">Get Started</a></li>
  <li><a href="/get_involved">Get Involved</a></li>
  <li><a href="/news">News & Events</a></li>
  <li><a href="/subscribe">Subscribe</a></li>
</ul>
```

This gives you a very simple header, followed by a bulleted list of the links.  While that may not resemble what you see on the page *visually*, in fact it contains the same content and is just as functional.  It's also easily understood by search engines and screen readers.

Then you would use [image replacement techniques](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/) to swap the text with pictures.

Comment: I'd wrap it all in a `<header>`, remove the `class="title"` - you get it for free with `header > h1` or `header > h1:first-child` - also the `class=navigation` should probably be an id since you will probably only have one top navigation on your site, maybe a class + an id

Comment: I'm leaving out HTML5 elements for now, since you still need to deal with older versions of IE, and using a javascript polyfill might be too advanced for the OP.  Regarding IDs vs classes, I can see your point but I've come to agree with those who are against using IDs in almost all situations (mostly to avoid specificity headaches).

Comment: I see your concern that it might be a bit much to take in and I sympatize with that, but it could also be a little "waste of time" to teach old (hopefully soon outdated - fingers crossed) semantics... what a paradox :)

Comment: Here are some thoughts on why you should not use IDs (not written by me): http://oli.jp/2011/ids/